# List of objects: how to extract attributes from a particular region or slice?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

This image from the numpy docs left me wondering. If it was a multidimensional list (or `ndarray`) containing objects with an attribute in common, how can one extract it from *specific parts?*

[image]

I have read other questions about how to extract attributes from an entire list and extracting from rows and columns would be easy using list comprehensions, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it, for instance, for the 2nd and 4th slices shown in the image, *especially* the 4th slice.

This would be useful for a board game I'm making, I could slice the board and check, for example, if a group of tiles have a particular value or if they share a specific attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to check if they have an attribute in common than you can reduce it to a 1D-Case by raveling the result of the indexing.

```
array = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
array[2::2,2::2] # Gives you: array([[12, 14], [22, 24]])
array[2::2,2::2].ravel() #Gives you: array([12, 14, 22, 24])
```

Since it seems 1D cases are solveable (with list comprehensions) for you that might just be the trick. But for list comprehensions you have to be aware that multidimensional arrays should be ravelled or flattened (see numpy documentation) if you don't want an array of `axis` as result.

For simple cases you might just want to use the `np.all` function without `flatten` or `ravel`:

```
#Just check if they are all multiplicatives of 2
np.all((array[2::2,2::2] % 2) == 0) # Gives you True
#Just check if they are all multiplicatives of 3
np.all((array[2::2,2::2] % 3) == 0) # Gives you False
```

But there is another way: numpy provides an `np.nditer` iterator (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html) and you can do pretty fancy stuff with this one. Just as an very easy example:

```
#Supposing you check for an attribute
def check_for_property(array, property_name, property_state):
   #property_name: str (The name of the property you want to check(
   #property_state: anything (Check if the property_name property of all elements matches this one)
   #The returns act as a shortcut so that the for loop is stopped after the first mismatch.
   #It only returns True if the complete for loop was passed.
   for i in np.nditer(array):
       if hasattr(i, property_name):
          if getattr(i, property_name) != property_state:
              return False #Property has not the same value assigned
       else:
          return False # If this element hasn't got this property return False
   return True #All elements have the property and all are equal 'property_state'
```

In case you want it small (and your check is relativly easy) then a list-comprehension with `np.all` and `np.nditer` could look like:

```
np.all(np.array([i.property for i in np.nditer(array[2::2,2::2])]) == property_state)
```

Comment: Very informative and detailed answer! I followed this same approach shortly after posting my question, though I was using `flatten()`. I may switch to `ravel()` since I don't need a copy of the array. And I think list comprehensions or generator expressions are good enough for quick checks, but it's great to know about how to use `nditer` in loops. Also, your very first line (`np.arange(50).reshape(5,5)`) throws a `ValueError` on my end. Thank you vey much!

Comment: @absay As long as you don't alter tha data `ravel` is better, but `flatten` provides the same functionality. Sorry about the first line, that was a C&P error on my side, I'll change it.